# How do i put two cards beside each other?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get two cards beside each other but no matter what I do they end up underneath each other. I have them in the same row, in the same container but it still won't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Home page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="search-bar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class ="container-fluid">

     <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-2" style="width: 170px;">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Avatar" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
            <div class="container">
              <h6><b>John Doe</b></h6>
            </div>
          </div> 
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Avatar" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
                <div class="container">
                  <h6><b>John Doe</b></h6>
                </div>
          </div>

          </div>


        </div>
      </div>     
      </div>

      </body>
      </body>
      </html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Home page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="search-bar.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2" style="width: 170px;">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Avatar" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
          <div class="container">
            <h6><b>John Doe</b></h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Avatar" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
          <div class="container">
            <h6><b>John Doe</b></h6>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on the problem and solution you want...try to add image so that we can understand your problem.

Comment: NOTE: I made a snippet of your code to easily reveal the syntax issues by proper formatting - I left the original for comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Some containers removed. Your cards are now in a column each and both columns are inside a row.

`col-6` will make the columns 50% width each, you can make them thinner or wider using `col-1` to `col-12`. The cards will also fill that width as long as you **do not** dictate any card sizes in your CSS!!

Adding `class="img-fluid"` to the images and removing the styled size you entered will make the images stay at the column width no matter the screen size.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
         <div class="card">
            <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Avatar">
            <h6><b>John Doe</b></h6>
         </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
         <div class="card">
            <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Avatar">
            <h6><b>John Doe</b></h6>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two syntax errors:

- An extra div closer `</div>`
- and extra body closer `</body>`
- I added `class="col"` to the second card div
- Note by using the forced width on the first column, on small screens you may not see all of that image in columns 1 and 2 set by `col-2` you have.
- I removed some `style=` and made classes instead (always try to style wit CSS and classes

We have NO idea what your CSS file does and now this may impact answers negatively.  This is the main reason I left some of the markup I would normally NOT do such as the containers around the text on the cards.

```css
.first-column {
  width: 170px;
}

.card-image {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Home page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="search-bar.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="card first-column">
          <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Avatar" class="card-image">
          <div class="container">
            <h6><b>John Doe</b></h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Avatar" class="card-image">
          <div class="container">
            <h6><b>John Doe</b></h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Second example with standard card use

```css
.card-image.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
}

.card-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Avatar" class="card-image card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h6 class="card-title">John Doe</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" alt="Avatar" class="card-image card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h6 class="card-title">John Doe</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```